# Parsing a string returned from ckeditor using javascript string methods

Tags: javascript, string, ckeditor, text-parsing

I am trying to get a certain area of data out from ckeditor. In order to do that I use the following code

```
function get_body_html(){
    var email = CKEDITOR.instances['message'].getData();
    var before_body = header_to + to + to_subject + subject + subject_body;
    var s_index = email.indexOf(before_body)+before_body.length;
    var e_index = email.indexOf(body_footer);
    return email.substring(s_index,e_index);
}
```

For some reason that works when I do this on page load

```
CKEDITOR.instances.message.setData(header_to + to + to_subject+ 
subject + subject_body + body_text + body_footer);
get_body_html();
```

it works correctly and gives me the same string that is contained in body_text.

But when I do this

```
body_text = get_body_html();
CKEDITOR.instances.message.setData(header_to + to + to_subject + subject + 
subject_body + body_text + body_footer);
```

in an onclick function it gets the wrong indexs somehow. Sometimes it can't find the string and returns -1 other times it just gets a weird index that doesn't make sense. These index variations only happen when my code is changed to tackle the problem a different way. So if it is the wrong indices like -5 and 2 then those would continue to be the wrong indices until I made a code change.

Comment: should't you call `get_body_html()` after setting the message data just as before?

Comment: I am trying to get the body html before I overwrite it using setData() so switching the two would defeat the purpose. The one where I set the data before was just a test to see if my logic even worked in the first place.

Comment: Well then the problem is in what data does the body have. Try to output/log your email variable and check if it does contain your `before_body` and `body_footer` if not then maybe you should use replace instead of substring, something like: `email.replace(before_body,'')`

Comment: The body has the proper data when logging/output the data from the editor. The problem is the indexOf method in java can't seem to find it even though it's there.

Comment: Well, how about you post a fiddle with sample data to try and sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two facts that you should know about `editor.setData`.

1. In some cases it is asynchronous (it depends on the type of editor). That's why it also accepts a callback. Therefore any code that is meant to be executed after `setData()` should be executed in that callback.
2. It never is asynchronous before editor is ready. In this period (between editor initialization and `instanceReady` event) it works in a different mode - it just caches the set value and on `getData()` it returns exactly that value.

So, as I see on page load you call synchronously `setData()` and `getData()` - your function works because you get the value you're expecting to get.

But then, when you try to `getData()` when editor is already ready you get the HTML parsed, fixed, processed and perhaps differently formatted by CKEditor. I guess that your `indexOf()` checks are not enough to handle this. You have to rethink your function - e.g. regexp can help.

What also can help is removing `htmlwriter` plugin, which formats HTML in a way which may make it harder for you to work with it. E.g.:

```
config.removePlugins = 'htmlwriter';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work. So the htmlwriter was one of the problems because it must add spaces in between by HTML tags. The other issue I found is that it strips some of the semicolons out in some of the style attributes. Overall CKEditor does a lot of formatting of the source which makes it very hard to index correctly but it's pretty much a trial and error thing. I ended up using the search JavaScript method for strings which can take a regular expression but I used it the same way indexOf would be used so I don't really know if that made a difference or not.

Comment: It should be noted that it strips out semicolons even if htmlwriter is turned off.